# Proving the equivalence of some different definitions of continuity

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I wanted to verify the correctness of my solution to a basic point-set topology exercise. Also, could the ($2 \leftrightarrow 3$) component of the proof be made more direct and enlightening?

**Proposition.** Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from space $X$ to space $Y$. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. given any open $U \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open,
2. given any closed $F \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed, and
3. given any subset $A \subseteq X$, $f(\mathsf{Clos}(A)) \subseteq \mathsf{Clos}(f(A))$.

*Proof*.

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from space $X$ to space $Y$.

(1 $\leftrightarrow$ 2) $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open $U \subseteq Y$ $\leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U)^c$ is closed for every open $U \subseteq Y$ $\leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U^c)$ is closed for every open $U \subseteq Y$ $\leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U^c)$ is closed for every $U^c \subseteq Y$ where $U$ is an open set of $Y$ $\leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for every closed $F \subseteq Y$ since complements of opens are exactly the closed sets.

(2 $\rightarrow$ 3) Suppose $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for every closed subset $F \subseteq Y$. We need to show that $f(\mathsf{Clos}(A)) \subseteq \mathsf{Clos}(f(A))$ for every subset $A \subseteq X$. Let $A \subseteq X$ be an arbitrary subset of $X$ and let $x \in \mathsf{Clos}(A)$. It remains to be shown that $f(x) \in \mathsf{Clos}(f(A))$ i.e. $x \in f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(f(A)))$. By assumption, we have that $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(f(A)))$ is closed so it suffices to show that $x \in \mathsf{Clos}(f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(f(A))))$. We are done if we can show that every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(f(A)))$. Let $U$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$. Because $x \in \mathsf{Clos}(A)$, $U$ must contain some $a \in A$. Clearly, $f(a) \in f(A) \subseteq \mathsf{Clos}(f(A))$ which is to say that $a \in f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(A))$.

(3 $\rightarrow$ 2) Suppose $f(\mathsf{Clos}(A)) \subseteq \mathsf{Clos}(f(A))$ for every subset $A \subseteq X$. Let $F \subseteq Y$ be a closed subset. We need to show that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed i.e. $\mathsf{Clos}(f^{-1}(F)) \subseteq f^{-1}(F)$ which is equal to $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(F))$ because $F$ is closed. Let $x \in \mathsf{Clos}(f^{-1}(F))$. We have by assumption that
\begin{equation*}
    f(\mathsf{Clos}(f^{-1}(F))) \subseteq \mathsf{Clos}(f(f^{-1}(F))) = \mathsf{Clos}(F)
\end{equation*}
meaning $f(x) \in \mathsf{Clos}(F)$ i.e. $x \in f^{-1}(\mathsf{Clos}(F))$ which was what we needed.